# Display blocks in line with scroll

Tags: css, layout

I have folowing code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
        <li class="item">a</li>
        <li class="item">bb</li>
        <li class="item">ccc</li>
        <li class="item">dddd</li>
        <li class="item">eeeee</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.item{
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VSfHS/183/

And i need to display items in one row with scrollable overflow.
Number of items is dynamic, so I can't preset width of content.

Comment: @ANK - this won't work.  If he adds more elements they will overflow onto the next line which is not want he wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.
http://jsfiddle.net/VSfHS/184/

The solution is `white-space: nowrap`